# Ansible: Load contents of files in directory into dict

Tags: ansible

## TL;DR

In ansible, how do I load the contents of the files in a directory into a `dict`, such that the `key: value` pairs are `filename: 'file_contents'`?

## The rest of the story...

I have a use case in Ansible, in which I need to provide the contents of a number of files to a helm chart, so that the helm chart can convert them to a `ConfigMap` for later inclusion in a pod.

The structure of the directory is:

```sh
foo/
  bar.txt
  baz.txt
  bat.txt
```

I essentially need to convert the files to:

```yaml
config_map:
  bar\.txt: 'contents of bar.txt'
  baz\.txt: 'contents of baz.txt'
  bat\.txt: 'contents of bat.txt'
```

When doing this as a shell script, I simply iterate over the files, and create a set of options in the form:

```sh
--set-file configMap.bar\\.txt=foo/bar.txt
```

What it seems to me that I **should** be able to do is dynamically build the `dict` `config_map` and then pass it to `helm` as follows:

```yaml
- name: 'sample playbook'
  tasks:
    - name 'install helm chart'
      helm:
        ...
        values:
          configMap: '{{ config_map }}'
        ...
```

The following task **displays** the files just fine, but I am at a loss regarding how to get to the next step.

```yaml
- name: 'test fileglob'
  debug:
    msg: '{{ lookup("file", "{{ item }}") }}'
  loop: '{{ lookup("fileglob", "foo/*.txt").split(",") }}'
```

## Edit

On further consideration, it seems to me that something like the following might work:

```yaml
- name: 'mytask'
  execute_jinja2: '{{ vars["config_map"][item.split("/")[-1]] = lookup("file", "{{ item }}") }}'
  loop: '{{ lookup("fileglob", "foo/*.txt").split(",") }}'
```

...except I haven't been able to determine how to execute an arbitrary Jinja2 statement like that, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more options.

- The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        config_map: "{{ config_map|default({})|
                        combine({item|basename: lookup('file', item)}) }}"
      with_fileglob: "foo/*.txt"

    - debug:
        var: config_map
```

give the expected result

```yaml
  config_map:
    bar.txt: contents of bar.txt
    bat.txt: contents of bat.txt
    baz.txt: contents of baz.txt
```

---

- The next option is to create a file and include it. The tasks below give the same result

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/config_map.yml"
        content: |
          {% for file in q('fileglob', 'foo/*.txt') %}
          {{ file|basename }}: {{ lookup('file', file) }}
          {% endfor %}
      tags: configure

    - include_vars:
        file: config_map.yml
        name: config_map

    - debug:
        var: config_map
```

The advantage is that you can run such a playbook with the tag `-t configure` and create the file

```yaml
shell> cat config_map.yml 
bar.txt: contents of bar.txt
baz.txt: contents of baz.txt
bat.txt: contents of bat.txt
```

In the next run, you simply include this file.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know about the basename filter. However, when I attempted the `{{ config_map | default({}) | combine(...) }}`, I got the following error: `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'config_map' is undefined` **Edit:** Just tried the `default({})` again, and it worked just fine; must've had a typo the first time.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, a lot of [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).